# Use google dataflow without maven and eclipse

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-platform

I want to use google dataflow without maven and eclipse in unix with java. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can certainly use Dataflow without Eclipse. We offer a plugin just as a convenience.

And you are also not required to use maven itself. However, dependency management is a hard enough problem that you are going to want to use an existing solution. There are many build tools that understand the POM-style dependencies and communicate with Maven Central. A few such tools are Apache Maven, Apache Ant (via Apache Ivy), Gradle, and SBT.

Comment: Hey I was actually looking for using google dataflow libraries in an independent piece of code which i can compile and run it without using any of the build tools like maven, ant, gradle etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what it means to have an independent piece of code which you can compile and run. The Dataflow SDK has real dependencies that you do have to provide. You can always put the Dataflow JAR on your classpath along with all of its transitive dependencies, but I don't recommend this.